# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionError: database "dbname" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

While trying to connect to a DB instance running the PostgreSQL database engine on Amazon RDS.

I have checked the environment variables and the values are set correctly.

However, when I run `npm run dev` I encounter the error below

`(node:32031) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionError: database "database-1" does not exist`

My DB is publicly accessible and security groups have been checked to be correct(allows inbound and outbound connection).

Answer (score 1):

Was able to solve this by using the default database name `postgres` for the env --dbname option.